# Where is local redis database (db)?

Tags: redis, homebrew

I can't find where is redis database which was installed with brew.

It's very hard to find. Where can I find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's under:**

`/usr/local/var/db/redis`

Answer (score 0):

Due to changes in macOS, it is nowadays in:
`/opt/homebrew/var/db/redis/`